# $f$ is upper function but $-f$ is not

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am learning about lebesgue integrals on my own using Apostol, and am stuck on an exercise. 
Let $\{r_1,r_2,...\}$ denote the set of rational numbers in [0,1] and let $I_n=(r_n-4^{-n},r_n+4^{-n}) \cap I$. Let $f(x)$ =1 if $x \in I_n$ for some $n$ and let $f(x)=0$ otherwise. The end goal of this exercise is to show that $f$ is an upper function, but $-f$ is not. I am stuck on part (c) of this exercise:

If a step function $s$ satisfies $s(x) \leq -f(x)$ on I, show that $s(x) \leq -1$ almost everywhere on $I$.

I tried to show this by showing $f(x) \geq 1$ almost everywhere, but I am not convinced that's true anymore. Any suggestions on how I should proceed with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose $E_1 = \{x \in I : s(x) > -1\}$ has positive measure. Show there exists some $x \in E_1$ such that $s$ is constant on some interval $J$ containing $x$. Then note that $J$ contains some rational number $q$, but $s(q) \leq -1$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Your hint does make a lot of sense, but is there any way to do it without using a set with positive measure? In Apostol's book, this exercise occured in a section before a set with positive measure was introduced. Only sets of measure zero was defined. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, you could consider the finitely many intervals $J_1,J_2,\ldots, J_m$ on which $s$ is constant. Then suppose $s > -1$ on some $J_i$. Note that $J_i$ cannot contain any rationals.